# Stylesheet is not loading on firefox and IE!

Tags: theme-development

Hi I recently started to learn wordpress theme development and today I started my first worpress theme.For some reason my stylesheet get's loaded in chrome but not in firefox and IE the browsers I am using to test.

Something else I noticed is that it seems wordpress adds some additional styles on its own.Here's what I found on the source page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
 </style>
```

This are not styles I added.

I have tryed to use `<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri() ?>`

```
                 <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')
```

But none of theme seem to load the styles.

Here is my entire header code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>
       <?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo('name'); }elseif ( is_category() ) { single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name'); }
            elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title();}
            elseif (is_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ': '; single_post_title();}
            else { wp_title('',true); } 
       ?>
   </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>" media="screen"/>
   <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" type ="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   <?php wp_head() ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something else I noticed is that it seems wordpress adds some additional styles on its own.Here's what I found on the source page:

When you browse your blog while logged in, wordpress adds `28px` margin to top of html/body to make space for their -  [Wordpress Toolbar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Toolbar)

**And here's line of code from my theme which is correctly loading stylesheet -**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: well it seems that this style is being added to my index.php file.This should not happen right?

Comment: it solved the problem of adding the stylesheet but it still still adds the aditional css with from what I know it should not be added on the theme file isen't that true?

Comment: if you don't want to show admin mar you can disable it.

Comment: @user985482 That 28px margin is correctly being added, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `Administration > Users > Your Profile` and turn of admin bar to not add those extra stylesheet.

Comment: Thanx that was it